# How to move to KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments

i use Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME as default desktop environment.
How to remove GNOME and install KDE as desktop environment ?

Comment: I personally prefer gnome, work in it is just faster with gnome shell and it's window management, but it's is very individual. You can install KDE next to the Gnome and test it without removing Gnome jet.

Comment: For installation check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/138063/installing-kde-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: "And tell me which is better among KDE and GNOME" is a subjective question and possible flame war >:-)

Comment: Yeah nobody can say what you'll prefer. Try it and see.

Answer (score 3):

You can install KDE using this command

```
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

To remove Gnome:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove liborbit2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-desktop
```

Comment: Rather than installing the simple metapackage, consider installing the APT task. See [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252056/88802)