# Ubuntu 14.04 to Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

I'm new here, so please excuse me if this question has been asked before. Also, I'm new to this whole Linux/Ubuntu etc thing, so this may be a silly question. :-)

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Aspire 5349 a few days ago. It now dual boots with Win 7. I find that it's very good and I quite like the GUI, but a wee bit 'jerky' on graphics rich Facebook games (using Chrome).

My question is regarding changing to Kubuntu instead. I think that I prefer the look of that, and is it possible to replace U with K? I'd rather not 'trio-boot'.

I'm not a complete techie, so please be gentle with me (!)

Comment: All the *buntu desktops can be burnt to a USB so you can try them first. Boot from one of those and try it for your self don't install just try if you prefer KDE see this question [Installing KDE in Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/138063/107450). The same steps will work in 14.04 as they did in 12.04.

Comment: Flagging to close as **primarily opinion based** as only you know what you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you can use Kubuntu. Although, I would say at this point that you only install Kubuntu besides Ubuntu and not try to replace it.

Just open your Synaptic Package manager/ Software centre and choose "Kubuntu-Desktop" package and "GDM" login manager. Install these.

Once done, you need to reboot. The system would still be dual-boot. So, on Grub, you would select Kubuntu. But, on login screen, you would be given a choice to select a session "Kubuntu" or "Ubuntu" before entering your password.

Easy.

Comment: Can't find "GDM" login manager in Software Centre.

Comment: My bad. you could try LDM (Light desktop manager) or KDM (Kubuntu Desktop Manager.) In all probability, you already have LDM installed. So just install Kuduntu-desktop and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah, I have LDM, so just installed KD. Once I rebooted it came up with the usual Ubuntu or Win 7 choices - no Kubuntu. I chose U and then the Kubuntu screen came up. Once that went it just booted into the same Ubuntu desktop, tho'.

Comment: Do you have automatic-login enabled (Do you need to enter password at Kubuntu screen?) If password is not required, then you need to change Session-type to K in System-settings.
<br/> If you get a screen to enter password, then on the login screen, at the bottom left of the screen, click Options and select K.

Comment: I have it working now, up to a point. I ran "sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop" However it wants a username & password. I never set one up. I can't go past this screen...

Comment: Every Ubuntu installation asks for a password to be set up during installation. It is mandatory. So if possible please find out the password that was setup during the 1st ubuntu installation (not this Kubuntu-dekstop installation.)

Comment: Apologies for this 'extended discussion', but I can't move this to chat as I don't have enough reputation yet. If I find the password, will I still need to provide a username? If I can't find/remember anything is there anything I can do?

Comment: Just wondering, when you installed Kubuntu-desktop, did it not ask for a paswword? There are ways to recover any lost info, but that's more technical. Moreover I think since you were recently able to installed software, you have some kind of access information yourself. If you remember the password you provided, we could work out something easier.

Comment: Well . . . there is a password I'm asked for whenever I install something from the Software Centre. I think I was asked for this when I typed in "sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop". If this is the password I should be using, that's fine, however it's still asking for a username. I  just wanna say thanks for all your help @ashish. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. that's the password you need to enter. And username would be the name of your home folder you saw every time you started nautilus/Nemo. (e.g., /home/david, here david is your username.) If you found the answer useful, please mark it as accepted. Welcome.